# Two ways to fit a function on data points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fitting, logarithmic-scale

I have the following data:

```
eR = {1.1*10^-4 , 3.3*10^-4 , 1.1*10^-3 , 2*10^-3 , 
   3.3*10^-3 , 5.8*10^-3 , 1.1*10^-2 , 1.9*10^-2 , 3.3*10^-2 , 
   5.8*10^-2 , 1.1*10^-1} ;
NoDF = {2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 7 , 11 , 18 , 21 , 35};
DSF = Transpose@{eR , NoDF};
```

Now, what I would like to do is to linearly fit a curve on the above set of points. Thus, I use the following

```
fitF = FindFit[DSF, a*n^b, {a, b}, n];
```

So, when I plot the data and the curve together they look ok. First I plot the data point

```
plot1F = {DSF } // 
  ListLogLogPlot[#, Joined -> False, FrameTicks -> All ,  
    Frame -> True] &
```

Secondly, I plot the fitting curve

```
a = Last[First[fitF]];
b = Last[Last[fitF]];
func[x_] := a x^b;
Data = Table[func[x] , {x , 1.1*10^-4 , 1.1*10^-1 , 0.00001}];
XF = Table[x , {x , 1.1*10^-4 , 1.1*10^-1 , 0.00001}];
DATAfit  = Transpose@{XF , Data};
plot2F = {DATAfit} // 
  ListLogLogPlot[# , PlotRange -> All , FrameTicks -> All,  
    Frame -> True] &
```

Then, I put them together

```
Show[plot1F , plot2F , PlotRange -> All]
```

The result looks ok for me. But then I was asked to change the function and first, take the logarithm of the points and then fit them with a + b*x function. So first I took the logarithm of the data point

```
DSFL = Transpose@{Log[eR] , Log[NoDF]};
```

and then fit the data

```
fitF2 = FindFit[DSFL, c + d n, {c, d}, n];
 c = Last[First[fitF2]];
 d = Last[Last[fitF2]];
funcL[x_] := c + d x;
```

But when I plot the data, it seems that there is something wrong with my plots. Because the curve does not fit the data

```
DataL = Table[funcL[x]  , {x , 1.1*10^-4 , 1.1*10^-1 , 0.00001}]; 
XF = Table[x , {x , 1.1*10^-4 , 1.1*10^-1 , 0.00001}];
DATAL = Transpose@{XF , DataL};
plot3F = {DATAL} // 
  ListPlot[# , PlotRange -> All , FrameTicks -> All,  Frame -> True] &
Show[plot1F , plot3F , PlotRange -> All]
```

Now, I want to know if there is something wrong with my function or code. Because I know that the method is correct and I should be able to fit the data with a c + d*x function.

Comment: You don't want to take logs of the x axis values, just the y axis values.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for your response. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I don't think that would solve the problem. Thanks by the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think not all your data adheres to your model, or perhaps your model is too simple to fit here.

Here is a somewhat simplified approach to your problem. Let's start with fitting the data directly to the non-linear model (in general a preferable approach, since no distortion is introduced in error statistics):

```
NonlinearModelFit[DSF, a n^b, {a, b}, n]
Plot[
  %[n], Evaluate@Flatten@{n, MinMax@eR},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point@DSF}
]
```

[image: non-linear fit result]

[image: non-linear fit plot]

That's not bad.

---

Let's transform the data and try the *linear* fit then:

```
logData = Log10@DSF;

LinearModelFit[logData, x, x]
Plot[%[x], 
  Evaluate@Flatten@{x, MinMax@Log10@eR},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point@logData}
]
```

[image: linear fit results]

[image: linear fit plot all data]

This is also not bad, but definitely the first two points don't seem to fit in the linear model.

---

We can try to redo the fit by excluding those points:

```
LinearModelFit[logData[[3 ;;]], x, x]
Plot[%[x], 
  Evaluate@Flatten@{x, MinMax@Log10@eR},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point@logData}
]
```

[image: linear fit results without first two points]

[image: linear fit plot without the first two points]

This is a lot better; notice also that the slope parameter here is numerically very close to the fitted exponent from the non-linear model fit, as it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. Is it possible to express the second fitting function 1.81333 + 0.451063x in form of a n^b?

Comment: `Exp[1.81333]*n^0.45106` yields `6.1308 n^0.4510` to convert the fit in logarithmic space back to the original form. In general the log of `a * n^b` results in `Log[a] + b*Log[n]`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, 1.81333+ 0.451063 x can be expressed as           
 C*x^0.451063, where C is a constant. Am I right?

Comment: @MarcoB I mis-clicked a downvote on your answer and just noticed. Now it is stuck. Do you know any way to get it changed to an up vote? Apologies for the mis-click

Comment: @JackLaVigne No worries! I've taken the opportunity to make some cleanup changes to my answer. Due to the edit, you should now be able to modify your vote, if you wish to :-)

Comment: I don't know if it should be considered a mis-click, @JackLaVigne.  Removing inconvenient data points for a better fit generally warrants a downvote in my book.  However, I think it has been phrased that the model is inadequate to describe the data and removing those offending data points attempts to make that point.  Is that correct?

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for the edit. MIs-click corrected.

Comment: @JimBaldwin In principle I agree that removing points to improve a fit is a terrible thing to do, but in this case I suspect that the model is at fault at the lowest end, probably for physical / instrumental reasons (for instance I suspect that a noise floor may have been reached, and that was not accounted for in the model). That was why I mentioned that the model is probably inadequate or incomplete in this case. Moreover, although I am generally wary of linearization, I have to admit that in this case it highlights the problems with those initial points better than the nonlinear fit.